# Uso de fetch javascritp. Y recibir datos con express

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express, ecmascript-2015, ecmascript

Tengo una duda.
Verán estoy enviando los datos de mi formulario con ayuda de `fetch` así:

```
const formSignin = document.querySelector('#formSignin');
formSignin.addEventListener("submit", event => {
  event.preventDefault();
  const formDataSignin = new FormData(formSignin);

  fetch('/signin', {
      method: 'post',
      body: formDataSignin
    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
      //Alguna respuesta
    });
});
```

Pero una vez que llega al servidor `nodejs`, dice que los datos están indefinidos.

```
console.log(req.body.user);
```

En cambio con la herramienta `Postman`, puedo enviarlos sin problema y se reciben bien.

Alguien podría tener una solución

Comment: Me equivoco si digo que vienes del video tutorial de Carlos Azaustre? XDD Yo también tengo el mismo problema actualmente. He llegado a la conclusión que el FormData fuerza a multipart/form-data y no a application/x-www-form-urlencoded, por lo que body-parse puede trasnformalo a JSON lo que venga del formulario (ver https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser/issues/181). Conseguiste solucionarlo finalmente?